# Rewrite uri to remove www in nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I have an unknown number of domains that match a pattern like `www.abc123.example.com`. Where the number after "abc" is unknown. I thought perhaps I could use a rewrite rule with the regex `~*(www\.abc\w+)`

Something like:

```
server_name ~*(www\.abc\w+)
rewrite ~*(www\.abc\w+)\.example\.com (abc\w+)\.example\.com;
```

Unfortunately, that does not seem to work, and the uri does not change.
My other thoughts were perhaps attempting to set/rewrite the $uri value but I have been unsuccessful with that as well.

I am not sure if I am failing to match the uri value or failing to rewrite the uri (or both).

I was able to fine this:

```
if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)) {       
set $host_without_www $1;
rewrite ^(.*) http://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
}
```

Unfortunately, that rewrites all 'www' traffic and not just www.abc123.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Reduce the scope of the regular expression, for example: `^www\.(abc.*\.example\.com)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following approach:

```
server {
    server_name ~ ^www\.(?<newdomain>abc[0-9]+\.example\.com)$;

    return 301 https://$newdomain$request_uri;
}
```

This will match domains `www.abcN.example.com`, where `N` is one or more digits. The regular expression will capture the part `abcN.example.com` into variable `$newdomain`.

Then in the return statement we build the destination URL using the variable captured earlier and the URI part of the request.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you